# Database of analysed positions with corresponding scores

Tags: engines, database, evaluation

I am looking for a database with many various chess positions with a corresponding engine score. Something like (position, score):

- `6r1/3k4/4b1rB/p2p1R2/1pp5/8/PP5Q/7K w - - 1 39`   **1.25**
- `rn2nrk1/1b2qppp/p3p3/1p2P3/3N4/2NB2Q1/PPP3PP/2KR3R w - - 1 15`   **0.49**
- `4nr2/r4p1k/4p1p1/p2qP2P/1p6/3B1P2/PPP5/2K3RR w - - 0 25` **6.91**
- `2kr2nr/1bq2p1p/ppp1p1p1/2b5/N3P3/4BP2/PPP2QPP/1K1R1B1R b - - 1 13` **-10**

I am hoping to have a database with significant amount of positions (~1 million), where positions are evaluated with at least 3 seconds of thinking of a strong engine.

The

- bigger the number of positions
- the longer the thinking time of an engine (or the ply lookahead)
- the stronger the engine
- the more different score of positions (+0.1, +4.2, + 9.1, -8.7)

the better. I know that I can write a program that gives stockfish tasks to calculate the score of various positions, but it will take a couple of months to calculate scores for 1 million positions.

Comment: Are you planning to train an evaluation function?

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster yes :-) trying to write a predictor

Comment: Cool. Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

[Here you can find](https://www.kaggle.com/c/finding-elo/data) a database with 50,000 games and engine scores after every move. That should translate to 80*50,000 = 4 million positions. Unfortunately the engine evaluations are by stockfish with only one second per position, which isn't very much.

You might also try to parse the [Chessok Opening Tree](http://chessok.com/?page_id=352), or to get the commercial version of it. Those evaluations are possibly better.